# SelectedIndex or SelectedItem of ListView inside SemanticZoom

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, listviewitem

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App** (WINRT). I have a Listview which shows grouped items. Categories and subcategories inside it. user can select any subcategory and it must save into a variable.

**XAML:**

```
  <SemanticZoom x:Name="CategorySemanticZoom" 
                                  IsZoomOutButtonEnabled="True"
                                  CanChangeViews="True"
                                   Grid.Row="1">
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                            <ListView x:Name="Category_ListViewDetail" IsSwipeEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True"
                                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                      IsZoomedInView="True" 
                                     ItemClick="Category_ListViewDetail_ItemClick">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>

                                            <TextBlock
                                                Text="{Binding SubCategoryName}" 
                                                FontSize="26"
                                                Margin="30,0,10,0" 
                                                FontWeight="ExtraLight"
                                                Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}" 
                                                SelectionHighlightColor="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_MediumBlueColor}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle>
                                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Border Background="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}" 
                                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        Margin="10,20,10,20" 
                                                        Tapped="Border_Tapped"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" 
                                                               FontSize="26"
                                                                Margin="10,4,10,4"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                FontWeight="ExtraLight" 
                                                               Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_BluishWhite_LightColor}"
                                                               SelectionHighlightColor="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_LightTileBorder}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                                                </Border>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                                                                       Margin="0 0 0 0"
                                                                       ItemHeight="55"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                                    </GroupStyle>
                                </ListView.GroupStyle>
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListView>
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                            <ListView x:Name="Category_ListViewSummary"
                                      Background="LightGray" 
                                      IsZoomedInView="False"
                                      Opacity=".85">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Background="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_DarkBlueColor}" 
                                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        Margin="10,10,10,10" >

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Group.CategoryName}" 
                                                               FontSize="26"
                                                                Margin="10,4,10,4"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                FontWeight="ExtraLight" 
                                                               Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_BluishWhite_LightColor}"
                                                               SelectionHighlightColor="{StaticResource DefaultTheme_LightTileBorder}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                                        </Border>


                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListView>
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                    </SemanticZoom>
```

**CS:**

```
        private void GenerateCategoryListFromResultObject()
        {
            CollectionViewSourceObject = new CollectionViewSource();
            CollectionViewSourceObject.IsSourceGrouped = true;


            MasterCategory mcat = GetCategoriesResultObject.MasterCategories[0];
            CollectionViewSourceObject.Source = mcat.Categories;

           // CollectionViewSourceObject.ItemsPath = new PropertyPath("Contacts");
            CollectionViewSourceObject.ItemsPath = new PropertyPath("SubCategories");

            Category_ListViewDetail.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSourceObject.View;
            Category_ListViewSummary.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSourceObject.View.CollectionGroups;
        }

 private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CategorySemanticZoom.IsZoomedInViewActive = false;
        }

        string SelectedCat_SubCategoryName = "";
        string SelectedCat_SubCategoryID = "";
        private void Category_ListViewDetail_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            SubCategory SubCategoryObject = (SubCategory)Category_ListViewDetail.SelectedValue;
            SelectedCat_SubCategoryName = SubCategoryObject.SubCategoryName;
            SelectedCat_SubCategoryID = SubCategoryObject.SubCategoryId.ToString();

            if (SelectedCat_SubCategoryID == null || SelectedCat_SubCategoryID =="")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                TapToSelectACategory_Underline_Run.Text = singletonInstance.TapToChangeCatString;
                UserCategory_Selected.Text = SelectedCat_SubCategoryName;
            }
            Popup_Category.IsOpen = false;

        }
```

**DataType/Class:**

```
 public class SubCategory
    {
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int SubCategoryOrderId { get; set; }
        public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }


    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryOrderId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

        public Category()
        {
            this.SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>(); //instantiate 
        }
    }

    public class MasterCategory
    {
        public int MasterCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int MasterCategoryOrderId { get; set; }
        public string MasterCategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public MasterCategory()
        {
            this.Categories = new List<Category>(); //instantiate 
        }
    }

    public class GetCategoriesResult
    {
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public List<MasterCategory> MasterCategories { get; set; }

        public GetCategoriesResult()
        {
            this.MasterCategories = new List<MasterCategory>(); //instantiate 
        }
    }
```

**The problem is that on selecting any subcategory, it always shows first  subcategory in variable:**

```
  SubCategory SubCategoryObject = (SubCategory)Category_ListViewDetail.SelectedValue;
            SelectedCat_SubCategoryName = SubCategoryObject.SubCategoryName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Category_ListViewDetail_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //SubCategory SubCategoryObject = (SubCategory)Category_ListViewDetail.SelectedValue;

    SubCategory SubCategoryObject = (SubCategory)e.ClickedItem;
}
```